Common Bitcoin Dos and Don'ts for this Site/Community
Could anyone provide me a list of all comments which would scrutinize what a person may do incorrectly in asking a question on this site/community?
If are there common mistakes you would typically see that you answer with a specific comment, please provide these as an answer in a list that is bullet pointed perhaps.
I am looking for items specific to the non-Meta Bitcoin Q&A site. I'm not sure if there would be common misconception or common comments someone would post to educate, criticize, etc.

Well, I assume you have seen the "Ask about…" and "Don't ask about…" in the tour.
We sometimes get programming questions that happen to be for a cryptocurrency related piece of software, but the issue is not specific to cryptocurrency. Those should rather be asked to Stackoverflow.
Often we get questions about investing in cryptocurrencies or mining thereof. We've declared that off-topic because those questions' answers tend to be localized in time.
We currently have two custom off-topic reasons:

Questions on current market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.
Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On the other hand, offerings in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly.

I'm not aware of a list of "canned comments" beside the auto-comments that get applied by flagging. Maybe we should start one. :)
